# Event bubbling with img tags?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I did some googling and figured I'm probably experiencing so called "event bubbling" that I've never heard of but are not surprised by it's existance. I want it to fire only once and I'm wondering how to fix this.

Basically, I have this small code snippet:

```
$('.bggallery_images').click(function () {      
    alert('test');      
});
```

This is supposed to fire once from a php snippet that basically adds an image of each image from a specific folder. It then outputs an echo string where each image has the class of "bggallery_images".

PHP snippet looks like this:

```
                    <?php
                    $dirname = "img";
                    $images = scandir($dirname);
                    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
                    foreach($images as $file)
                        {
                        if(!in_array($file, $ignore))
                            {                                                           
                                echo "<img class=\"bggallery_images\" src=\"$dirname/$file\" />";                                                               
                            };
                        }  
                    ?>
```

This all generates the html markup that looks like this for each image:

```
<img src="img/WhitePattern6.gif" class="bggallery_images">
```

What is happening here?

Here's the rendered output from FireBug:

```
<div id="gallery_lightbox" style="height: 215px; z-index: 4; display: block;">
                    <div id="close"></div>
                        <h2><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Velg " style="width: 39px; height: 20px;"><canvas width="49" height="23" style="width: 49px; height: 23px; top: -4px; left: 0px;"></canvas><cufontext>Velg </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="bakgrunnsbilde" style="width: 123px; height: 20px;"><canvas width="129" height="23" style="width: 129px; height: 23px; top: -4px; left: 0px;"></canvas><cufontext>bakgrunnsbilde</cufontext></cufon></h2>
                        <div class="bggallery_images">testererererer</div>
                        <img src="img/Bakgrunner/4462-v4.jpg" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/5922.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/BluePattern.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/Brown1.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/Brown2Pattern.jpg" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/BrownPattern.jpg" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/Brownn.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/GrayPattern.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/GreenPattern3.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/OrangePattern.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/PurplePattern.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/PurplePattern2.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/RedPattern3.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/RedPattern4.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/RedPattern5.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/Tiled_Wallpaper__Green_Texture_by_knitetgantt.png" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/WhitePattern4.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/WhitePattern5.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/WhitePattern6.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/WhitePattern7.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/WhitePurple.jpg" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/YellowPattern.gif" class="bggallery_images"><img src="img/Bakgrunner/vintage-wallpaper.jpg" class="bggallery_images">  
                     </div>
```

Edit: Here's the js.js file basically. I didn't include the kwicks slidemenu script though.

```
/* ********************************************** */
/* DOCUMENT READY */
/* ********************************************** */

$(document).ready(function () {
    bg_gallery();

});

/* ********************************************** */
/* Background gallery changer */
/* ********************************************** */

function bg_gallery() {

        // Sett nytt bakgrunnsbilde i CSSen 
        var originalBG = $('#wrapper').css('background-image');             

        $('.bggallery_images').click(function () {  
            var newBG = "url('" + $(this).attr('src');
            var fullpath = $(this).attr('src');
            var filename = fullpath.replace('img/Bakgrunner/', '');

            $('#wrapper').css('background-image', newBG);
            alert('test');

            // Lagre til SQL
            /*alert('Test');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'save_to_db.php', // The url to your function to handle saving to the db
                data: filename,
                dataType:'Text',
                type: 'POST',  // Could also use GET if you prefer
                success: function(data) {
                    // Just for testing purposes.
                    //alert('Background changed to: ' + data);
                }           

            });*/

    });     
        // Få frem galleriet

    $('.bggallery_current_image').click(function () {

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        $('#gallery_lightbox').css('height','215px'); // Sett høyde på lightbox-dings
        $('#gallery_lightbox').css('z-index','4'); // Sørg for at boksen er i øverste lag

        $('body').append('<div id="bggallery_overlay"></div>');
        $('#bggallery_overlay').css('height', $(document).height ());
        $('#bggallery_overlay').css('width', $(document).width ());     

        $('#bggallery_overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){$('#gallery_lightbox').fadeIn('slow');});

    });

     $('#close').click(function () {
         $('#bggallery_overlay').fadeOut('fast',function(){$("#bggallery_overlay").remove();}); //callback, vent
         $('#gallery_lightbox').fadeOut('slow');


    });
};


/* ********************************************** */
/* Content loader (swoosh ut-swosh inn) */
/* ********************************************** */

/* Load kun fra dynload-klasser, må wrappe en div f. eks rundt slike a href linker */

$('.dynload').die('click').live('click', function () {
    $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#ajaxloaderfridge').fadeIn('fast');
    var href = this.href + ' #content';
    var height_initially = $('#container').height();
    $('#content').slideUp('fast', function () {

        $('#content').fadeOut('fast');
        var height_current = $('#container').height();

        $(this).load(href, '', function (data) {
            createSlidemenus();
            bg_gallery();
            $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#ajaxloaderfridge').fadeOut('fast');

            $("#content").animate({
                height: 'show',
                opacity: 'show'
            }, 'normal');

            $('#content').show('fast');

            Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', {
                fontFamily: 'advent'
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
});

$(createSlidemenus);

function createSlidemenus() {
    $('#kontrollpanel .slidepanels').kwicks({
        min: 42,
        spacing: 3,
        isVertical: true,
        sticky: true,
        event: 'click'
    });
}
```

Comment: It's fires twice. I want it to fire once

Comment: Is it wrapped in a `<div class="bggallery_images">` or something similar?

Comment: No it's not. That's the weird thing. It's wrapped in a div called #gallery_lightbox. An ID in other words. Shouldn't affect it at all.

Comment: @Kenny Bones - It sounds like the javascript you have is being run twice, it it getting included twice somehow?

Comment: Do the images overlap at all due to the CSS? Also, your php looks fine but the HTML snippet above has no closing end ( <img /> ). If for some reason the HTML is coming out like that, its possible that the browser is reading each image as being nested inside the last.

Comment: Are you also using a Lightbox script on this page?

Comment: I copied the output from Firebug actually. The php code is supposed to close the tags. Do you see anything wrong in the echo of the php code? I posted it. @Nick, I also have other event handlers in the same script and those are not firing twice. So that would mean that it's not added double?

Comment: Quit double clicking your image.

Comment: Haha, you're funny :)
I can't even reach clicking twice since the alertbox appear immediatly. :)

Comment: I've added the js file and I think the problem lies within that. I tried to remove the click event handler from the function I was originally using and put it on document ready. And that lead to the alert box only firing once.

Comment: @kenny you should post your original code so we can learn what might have been the problem.

Comment: Well, I think I found the problem. I tried commenting out bg_gallery(); on document ready. And it also fixes the problem. So that means that bg_gallery() was being run on both document ready and through the content loader. But why would that result in a single click event to double? I mean, it's still just one click? Does code "double" like this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link to clarify event bubbling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

You can prevent bubbling by just returning "false" from the event handler:

```
$('.bggallery_images').click(function () {      
    alert('test');
    return false;
});
```

**Edit: This code works without producing two alerts so it must be something external to this.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gallery_lightbox" style="height: 215px; z-index: 4; display: block;">
        <div id="close"></div>
        <h2>
            <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Velg " style="width: 39px; height: 20px;">
                <canvas width="49" height="23" style="width: 49px; height: 23px; top: -4px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
                <cufontext>Velg</cufontext>
            </cufon>
            <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="bakgrunnsbilde" style="width: 123px; height: 20px;">
                <canvas width="129" height="23" style="width: 129px; height: 23px; top: -4px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
                <cufontext>bakgrunnsbilde</cufontext>
            </cufon>
        </h2>
        <div class="bggallery_images">testererererer</div>
        <img src="http://google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo13.png" class="bggallery_images"/>
        <img src="http://google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo13.png" class="bggallery_images"/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.bggallery_images').click(function () {      
            alert('test');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already tried this and it does not fix the problem. What does that imply?

Comment: It might not be a bubbling problem then. Do you have that same alert on any element that contains and an image?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do I have another alert connected to a class or id that these images are contained in? No I do not. Tried searching the js file for that word (alert) and there's just one result.

Comment: Hm, well that's frustrating. :)

Try this:
    $('.bggallery_images').click(function (e) {
        alert('test');

        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    });

By the way, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using FireFox. It also happens in IE. 
Tried your snippet and the alertbox appear twice.. 
I just love how things like this happen :)

Comment: Can you post the HTML/JavaScript from the rendered page somewhere? I'd like to play around with it if I can.

Comment: Like the output from FireBug? I can do that I suppose. 
Just to add some info, I created a div with the same class as the ones the images use and it alert came twice as well. Looks like its got nothing to do with img tags then

Edit: Updated the code and I know it looks like crap.. Also, I don't think the image tags are unclosed. Because notice the div in there with the same class and some dummy text inside? It happens there as well.

Comment: Check out the edit above. That code works without producing two alerts. I'd compare it to what you have and see what's functionally different.

Comment: Yeah, see my updated post for my js file. I think the problem is in that one. Tried removing the click handler from the function I was using it in "function gb_gallery()" and moved it to document ready instead. And the problem doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a test page from the html and js instruction you posted and can't reproduce your error- the alert only fires once. I'm using this for a jquery reference:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
```

and this at the end to start things up

```
<script>

    $('.bggallery_images').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });

</script>
```

you're doing something you're not telling us about or firebug is lying to you. it's possible the html that firebug is showing you (as it's interpreted) is different than the physical source of the page. can you post a complete example of your output which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I noticed something just now. If I remove this js snippet from the original function it was in and put it in document ready, it only fires once. I've updated the first post to include the entire js.js file I use.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the jquery .bind() method.

The following is taken from the jquery docs page

```
Example: Cancel a default action and prevent it from bubbling up by returning false:

$("form").bind("submit", function() { return false; })

Example: Stop an event from bubbling without preventing the default action by 
using the .stopPropagation() method.

$("form").bind("submit", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```